# Have a SQL script with multiple statements (exec stored procedures, selects etc). Want to force execution to occur in sequence

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've written a SQL script that clears a table, executes a series of stored procedures, and then output data with a series of select statements against the original table. The script looks something like this:

```
Truncate Table A

Exec [Batch Control SP]  --a stored procedure consisting of several other exec stored proc statements

Select * from A where [condition 1]

.

.

.

Select * from A where [condition Z]
```

The issue I'm finding is that some of the select statements are getting executed before the original Exec (and the other execs within) finishes. The process deadlocks from time to time and I believe this is the reason.

Is there a way to force the original exec to complete prior to any of the following selects?

Comment: It is not possible for a SQL Server batch to execute statements out of order.  Perhaps you are running multiple batches at the same time in your testing.

Comment: You could try wrapping the whole shebang in an exclusive [application lock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-getapplock-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to ensure that you aren't running two (or more) instances at the same time. Note that it will provide no protection against any other code that might be competing with this script.

Comment: Thanks all. What's confusing me is that when running this morning, several of the select statements ran before it failed due to a missing stored procedure (had renamed it prior). Perhaps the initial exec begins running and then it moves to the next statement before the first exec finishes? That batch control SP takes about 10 minutes to run, has 15 or so stored procedures that it executes. Just trying to understand what is happening.